# Using 'in' in where clause returns Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query works fine when I run it normally with params. But it results in error as soon as I make it dynamic.

I am pretty new to  SQL server.
When I print the query and run it, it works fine. But when run dynamically, it results in 'Subquery returned more than 1 value' error.

```
declare @query nvarchar(max) =  'Select * 
                    into #tempFilteredData              
                    from 
                    (
                    SELECT td.UserId AS [EmployeeID],w.NAME AS [EmployeeName],at.ActivityCode AS [ActivityType],td.TargetAssigned,td.Mkt_TerritoryId,
                    wd.WeekName + ''('' + CONCAT((RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(3),DATENAME(day, wd.WeekStartDate),0))), ''-'', CONVERT(CHAR(3),DATENAME(month, wd.WeekStartDate),0),''To'',
                    (RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(3),DATENAME(day, wd.WeekEndDate),0))), ''-'', CONVERT(CHAR(3),DATENAME(month, wd.WeekEndDate),0)) + '')'' AS weekName
                    FROM tblTargetDetails td
                    INNER JOIN FMC_CMaster..Worker w ON td.UserId = w.[Personnel Number]
                    INNER JOIN FMC_CMaster..[vwAuthenticateUser] vw ON vw.UserId = td.UserId and vw.Blocked=''No'' and vw.Closed=''No'' AND vw.AssetCode = ''MPH''
                    INNER JOIN tblActivityType at ON at.ActivityTypeId = td.ActivityTypeId
                    INNER JOIN WeekDetails wd ON wd.WeekId = td.WeekId
                    LEFT JOIN FMC_CMaster..Marketing_Hierarchy_AMM_Level mrktHAL ON w.[Personnel Number] = mrktHAL.TMH_Code 
                    WHERE td.CreatedBy =  ''' + @LoggedInUserId + '''  
                    AND mrktHAL.TMH_Code = ''' + @TMHCode + '''  

                    ) as p 
                    pivot(
                    MAX([TargetAssigned]) for [WeekName] in ('+RTRIM(LTRIM(@columnName))+')
                    ) as pvt

                    select * from #tempFilteredData where Mkt_TerritoryId IN ( '+(SELECT [MktTerritoryName] FROM @MktTerritoryNames)+' )'
        PRINT (@query)
        exec (@query)
```

I want to search for all the results that are being returned from @MktTerritoryNames in my temp table #tempFilteredData

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL? There's no need here to ther than to create an injection issue (which is a major security flaw). Take this out of a dynamic statement and properly parametrise it.

Comment: Dynamic sql is a requirement. I am making some columns dynamically for this result set

Comment: What do you suppose would happen If someone passed `''; DROP TABLE FMC_CMaster.dbo.Worker; --'` for `@TMHCode`?

Comment: [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.. Like you suggested, I have made it a normal query, and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

There are no subqueries in the first query expression.

That leads to the second.  What is this doing in the expression?

```
select * from #tempFilteredData where Mkt_TerritoryId IN ( '+(SELECT [MktTerritoryName] FROM @MktTerritoryNames)+' )'
```

I don't understand what this is even supposed to be doing.  Perhaps you want to run it *after* you've created the temporary table.  And, it doesn't need to be dynamic, just:

```
select *
from #tempFilteredData
where Mkt_TerritoryId IN (SELECT [MktTerritoryName] FROM @MktTerritoryNames);
```

Comment: It results in 'Invalid object name '#tempFilteredData''.